# PHP / MySQL INSERT not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm really struggling with this piece pf php code where I'm wanting to insert a message into a table using data gotten from another table.  Here is the code that I have:

```
$get_user_sql = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE id = '$member'";
$get_user_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_user_sql);
while($username = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_res)){
    $user = $username["username"];
};

$get_message_sql = "SELECT message FROM posts WHERE id = '1377077348-5922'";
$get_message_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_message_sql);
while($postsmessage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_message_res)){
    $postmessage = $postsmessage["message"];
};

$type = "liked";
$title = "New Like";
$message = "<a href=\"profile.php?member=$user\">$user</a> just liked your post:<br /><i>$postmessage</i>";

$insert_note_sql = "INSERT INTO notes (id, sender, recipient, type, title, message, date) VALUES('$id', '$member', '$recipient', '$type', '$title', '$message', '$time')";
$insert_note_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_note_sql);
```

I'm finding that if I remove $postmessage from the $message line everything works fine, but when I add it back in again the row isn't inserted. Can anyone see a reason for this?

Comment: What does mysqli_error() say? Have you echo'd out the query to make sure it is what you expect? What debugging have you done for this?

Comment: You need to escape all your data via `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: The query is being passed through JQuery so how can I echo out the error for this?

Comment: @user2516546 - you can always write any error messages to an error log on the server; you can also check the web server error log first to see if they're already being logged.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I have already done that for the data that's been passed into the script

Comment: Have you also checked the value of postmessage?

Comment: @Marijke Yes I wrote another script to test it out and it echo's fine, just not in this script for some reason

Comment: @user2516546 You have `$postmessage = $postsmessage["message"];` shouldn't that be `$postmessage = $postmessage["message"];` or is `$postsmessage` variable correct? As is the same for `while($postsmessage` wondering if making it as `while($postmessage` in singular like you have for the others.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, I don't think so. $postsmessage is from the fetch statement `$postsmessage = mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: @user2516546 Ok. It's because they looked all familiar to me. Sometimes people accidentally insert a character by mistake.

Comment: @user2516546 So `posts` and `notes` are two different areas right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's ok, I understand and yes they are 2 completely separate areas

Answer (score -1):

You're not escaping your values, propably some of your contents include quotes or other unescaped chars.

Try using [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) :

```
$postmessage = mysqli_real_escape_string($postsmessage);
```

You should escape **every value** before inserting it to the database, read more about [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your code has potential threats.

Comment: Do **not** use mysql_* functions since they are deprecated. And, besides, OP uses mysqli extension

Comment: It seems that your `$user` does not contain any quotes or other special chars. But it could, so you should escape every value.

Comment: Using mysqli_real_escape_string on $postmessage isn't working either?  My $user is determined by an ID that I have set so it will always be something like 12345678_1234

Comment: @user2516546 This may be irrelevant, but you say here about the ID being `12345678_1234` (underscore) yet your code has `1377077348-5922` with a hyphen. Like I said, may be irrelevant.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, that was my mistake - It is a dash and not an underscore